# Conflict cordova-plugin-googleplus and phonegap-plugin-push

Tags: cordova, phonegap-build, phonegap

My build got failed if i include both push notification and google plus plugin.

I am building the app using Phonegap Build.

```
PhoneGap (iOS / Android / Windows)
cli-8.0.0 (4.5.4 / 7.0.0 / 5.0.0)
```

Here is my config xml:

```
<plugin name="cordova-android-play-services-gradle-release"/>
<plugin name="phonegap-plugin-push" spec="2.1.2">
    <param name="PLAY_SERVICES_VERSION" value="16.+"/>
</plugin> 
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-googleplus" spec="5.2.1">
    <param name="REVERSED_CLIENT_ID" value="com.googleusercontent.apps.2445455956-8dfgs87asd5asd4a5sdasd4j"/>
    <param name="PLAY_SERVICES_VERSION" value="16.+"/>
</plugin>

<preference name="phonegap-version" value="cli-8.0.0"/>
<platform name="android">
    <allow-intent href="market:*" />
    <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="16"/>
    <preference name="android-targetSdkVersion" value="26"/>
<platform>
```

I am getting this error :

[image]

Any idea? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It should be related to a conflict of Google Play Service versions used by different plugins, this issue can be fixed installing this plugin https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-android-play-services-gradle-release

Comment: `<plugin name="cordova-android-play-services-gradle-release"/>`

**I have added the plugin but i am getting different error.**

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugGoogleServices'.
> Please fix the version conflict either by updating the version of the google-services plugin (information about the latest version is available at https://bintray.com/android/android-tools/com.google.gms.google-services/) or updating the version of com.google.android.gms to 11.0.1.

Comment: You should follow the error and update Google Play Version, try 16.0.0 or 16.0.1 https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup

Comment: **I have tried it but still getting the same error. Here is the code.**

`<plugin name="cordova-android-play-services-gradle-release"/>`
`<plugin name="phonegap-plugin-push" spec="2.1.2">`
 `<param name="PLAY_SERVICES_VERSION" value="16.0.1"/>`
`</plugin>`
`<plugin name="cordova-plugin-googleplus" spec="5.2.1">`
 `<param name="REVERSED_CLIENT_ID" value="com.googleusercontent.apps.244545596-8dfgs87asd5asd4a5sdasd4j"/>`
 `<param name="PLAY_SERVICES_VERSION" value="16.0.1"/>`
`</plugin>`

Comment: Try to remove and readd android platform, then build

cordova platform rm android
cordova platform add android

If the problem persist, try to use 16.0.0 and also update your post with the current error screenshot

Comment: I building application using build.phonegap.com. I have updated the post with current code and error screenshot.

Comment: At the moment I cannot access a repo of mine where I had similar issue, do another try put "16.+" as PLAY_SERVICES_VERSION. 
If you still have the problem update your post with the cordova cli version and android platform version. Good luck

Comment: Still same issue and updated post with the current code & error.

Comment: Did you edit by hand any the plugin's files? It is strange that there is still a reference to version 11.0.1. 
You can also try to update the android platform version to the latest 7.1.4 https://cordova.apache.org/announcements/2018/11/23/cordova-android-7.1.4.html

Good luck!

Comment: The maximum android platform version i can try in Phonegap Build is 7.1.2.**(PhoneGap (iOS/Android/Windows) cli-8.1.1 (4.5.5/7.1.2/6.0.1)**. I have tried that as well and its not working.

Comment: I am getting different error if we include googleplus before push plugin. Hereis the thread. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54322692/phonegap-build-error-plugin-with-id-com-google-gms-google-services-not-found